# Rstudio Error Quandl "code":"QECx02","message"

Tags: r, quandl

I am trying to import financial data from Quandl

```
library(Quandl)
library(xts)

currencies <- c("RUB", "USD", "JPY", "EUR", "CNY")
currencies <- paste("CURRFX/BRL", currencies, sep= "")

currency_ts <- lapply(as.list(currencies), Quandl, start_date="1999-01-01", end_date="2014-12-30", type="xts")
```

I have tried it for a few times with other currencies and it did work, but suddenly it stopped to work and started to give me this kind of error :

> Error: {"quandl_error":{"code":"QECx02","message":"You have submitted an incorrect Quandl code. Please check your Quandl codes and try again."}}

Comment: that won't fix your problem but use `paste0('CURRFX/BRL',currencies)`instead of `paste(...,sep="")`

Comment: retry your code one currency at a time to find the one with a problem

Comment: @etienne I have tried ... so the problem is with JPY. but it is strange becuase before I've changed the date range there were no problem with it. so what should I do next to import JPY data?
Thanks in advance

Comment: https://www.quandl.com/search?query=CURRFX%2FBRLJPY : no result on the website so I doubt you'll be able to import them.You can try to change the dates to find if there is a problem for a year or you can try to import those data from an other website/package

Comment: Any suggestion for other packages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this message is also displayed when the code is right but there is no quandl data available at the start date.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `quantmod`package with functions such as `getFX`, `getSymbols`and`getFinancials`... 
[This](http://www.r-bloggers.com/financial-data-accessible-from-r-part-iii/) website also lists different packages for accessing financial data with R